# Reduce expressions to values in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, lottie, bodymovin

I'm using an explainer template ([Pixity Land](https://videohive.net/item/pixity-land-character-explainer-toolkit/7139829)) to create some short animations with After Effects, and use a tool like Bodymovin/lottie to render HTML5 Canvas/SVG animations.

Unfortunately [Bodymovin](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web) has an issue with the expressions used in Pixity Land, and the rendered animations jump around jitter.  I don't have a lot of experience with After Effects and I'd rather not have to re-write the expressions.

I'm wondering if there's a way that I can reduce the expressions to values.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to convert expressions to keyframes. (I'm not sure why I was expecting it to be more complicated)

One right clicks on the property that has the expression and selects Keyframe Assistant > Convert Expression to Keyframes (or picks the option from the Animation menu).

Comment: It's called "Baking an Expression". If you want it more comfortable, you can use the tool EasyBake which gives you the opportunity to go back to the original expression if you want to change values.